# Predicting cycle flows assuming no traffic?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sdna

I'm trying to gauge the impact traffic has on levels of cycling. I have created a vehicle model which was used in creating a cycle model using cycle_roundtrip as the analysis. Following this, I have used the Learn and Predict tools to calibrate the betweenness variables produced from the model created by Integral with the measured cycle flows I have. From that, Predict was able to calculate the predicted number of cyclists accounting for levels of traffic.

However, how can I then create predicted flows assuming there are no levels of traffic?

I have created a new cycle model using Integral and assuming no traffic, however cannot use Learn as it would require cycle data calibrated in the presence of traffic.

Is there a way to have my no-traffic cycle Integral model produce predicted flows that I will be able to compare with the other cycle model flows accounting for traffic?

Comment: Set traffic to 1 car per millenial.

Comment: Are you using sDNA with ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: @PolyGeo both should work these days

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Firstly, check that you are using `cycle_roundtrip` for the radial metric as well as the analysis metric. If the radius is Euclidean then any analysis of flows will only account for changes in route choice due to changes in traffic, whereas you likely want to model changes to mode share as well e.g. extra cycling demand generated by the lack of traffic, hence the need for a `cycle_roundtrip` radius.

The procedure in https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15568318.2018.1432730 and https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-55669-8 is as below (the difference between these articles being only that the former first estimates levels of vehicle traffic while the latter uses road class as a proxy for it, which is easier and seems to work just as well):

1. Compute betweenness at multiple radii taking account of vehicle traffic (whether estimated from another sDNA model, or from road class) (sDNA Integral)
2. Fit a ridge regression model against measured cyclist flows in current (traffic) conditions. sDNA Learn can do this, or you can use R, etc.
3. Use sDNA Predict (or R, etc) to estimate cyclist flows on all links - not just your measured calibration flows - as predicted by the model in (2).
4. Compute betweenness again as in (1) but assuming all vehicle flows are 0
5. Use coefficients derived from (2) with betweenness derived from (4) to predict flows without traffic. sDNA Predict can do this using the model csv file output from sDNA Learn. If you are using different variable names, you can edit the model csv file to rename them as appropriate.
6. Subtract flow predictions in (3) from flow predictions in (5) to show predicted change in flows.